# float precision comparison by specific digit

Tags: python, math, rounding

How to test if two floats are identical until a specific digit?

I tried,

```
aa1 = 0.043403
aa2 = 0.043392
print(int(aa1*1000) == int(aa2*1000))
>> True
```

I want to follow this way, but my data include NAN value, it cannot convert it to intro anyhow.
I also tried math.isclose but it's tricky.

For example, I wanted to keep until 3 digits and applied the math.isclose

```
aa3 = 0.013041
aa4 = 0.012545
aa6 = 0.012945

print(math.isclose(aa3, aa4, abs_tol = 0.0001))
>>Flase
print(math.isclose(aa3, aa5, abs_tol = 0.0001))
>>True
```

But I want to get False for both cases.

Any simple idea??

Comment: Do you want to test the rounded values of the numbers up to 3 digits or just a cut after 3 digits?

Comment: I just want to ignore it after 3.

Comment: Do you really care about digit? Else "rel_tol" is close enough, but for decimal digits, you need to convert to decimal, so you should convert to string and compare strings [take care about lenght, dot, exponent,..]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes. I need specific Digit criteria

Comment: Judging from your comments to the other answers I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of python floating point types. While not mandated, you'll find that every implementation of python uses a IEEE 754 binary floating point type. Those types do not have base 10 digits, they have base 2 digits. Thus there is no such value as .1 in one of these floating point types. Your comment below "... 0.0014, 0.001399, threshold = 0.00001. Should be False..." is problematic because neither one of those values exists in a floating point type. Suggest you consider the `decimal` module.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I totally didn't know there is a concept behind the Python float. I will figure it out later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function which takes 2 numbers, `a` and `b`, and it has a preset threshold value. If the difference between `a` and `b` is less than the treshold, return True.

```
def isSame(a, b):
    return abs(a - b) < treshold
```

Where `treshold` can be a float. 0.0001 will ignore after the 3rd digit. Or cut the number as a string after 3 digits, and convert it back to float.

Edit, cut off method:

```
def isSame(a, b, digit):
    return float(str(a)[0:digit+2]) == float(str(b)[0:digit+2])
```

We ignore every number after the 3rd digit, in case your `digit = 3`.

Comment: I may miscalculated the treshold value. But you get the point.

Comment: well that was my question :/

Comment: Works for me. You mean 3 digits after the floating point, or with the leading 0 before the floating point?

Comment: Oh sorry, try this 0.0014, 0.001399, threshold = 0.00001. Should be False, but return True

Comment: I see your problem. This function says True, because basically those numbers are the same. What you need is cutting off the numbers after the 3rd digit. I'll post an update in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily using assertAlmostEqual
Below is the code

```
import unittest

unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual(value1,valu2,decimalUpto)
```

In your case it can be like

```
unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual(aa1 ,aa2 ,3)
```

Good Luck

Comment: It brings an error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '_formatMessage'

Comment: You have to use it in class .. There are many examples [here](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual/) Have a look on them

Answer (score 0):

`rel_tol` should be enough:

```
import math

def check(a, b):
    print(math.isclose(a, b, rel_tol=0.001), abs(a/b - 1.) < 0.001)

check(aa1, aa2)
check(aa3, aa4)
check(aa3, aa6)
```

gives the expected

```
True True
False False
False False
```

Note: the second calculation do not handle two equal zeros: easy to add. Not sure if underflow will affect it.